# IQueryable as List<T>

Tags: c#

I have a working service for retrieving books from a database, for which I am currently doing tests.
The service looks like this:

```
public async Task<List<Book>> GetBooks()
{
   ........
   ........
   IQueryable results = repository.Query();
   var list = await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => results as List<Book>);
   return list
}
```

This code works great when the application is running.

During the test, I can check with the debugger that the **results** variable has the value I need. But **list** variable has **null** meaning.
Here is the definition of my moq:

```
var books = new List<Book>();
for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
{
    books.Add(new Book
    {
        new Book { Id = i , Author = $"New Author {i}"}
    });
}

var mockBookRepository = new Mock<IBookRepository>();
mockBookRepository 
    .Setup(x => x.Query())
    .Returns(books.AsQueryable());
```

I need to do a test that will return values in a variable **list**.
Changing the **GetBooks ()** method is not valid

Comment: Instead of using "results as List<Book>" try "(List<Book>)results".
What error it gives to you?

Comment: you want results.ToList()

Comment: what about using `var result = await repository.Query().ToListAsync();`

Comment: You can cast IQueryable Type to List Type by .ToList() method.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to do an invalid cast you should be materializing

```
public async Task<Object> GetBooks()
{
   //........
   return await repository.Query().ToListAsync()
}
```

**PS**

Make sure  repository.Query() returns an `IQueryable<Book>` and not just `IQueryable`

Comment: I would happily return an IQueryable <Book>, but I use the **ApplyTo** method of the **ODataQueryOptions <Book>** class, which returns **IQueryable**.

Comment: If you're using OData, how can you claim that you're going to return a book, OData is dynamic, you should either return an Object instead, or if you know youre going to return a book you should be putting on the options which prevents selects and then putting the cast in the repository and returning a 'IQueryable<Book>'